# ASP (Classic) RecordSet value 'disappears' after first access, when MySQL TEXT data value

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc

A little while ago, in a peaceful world of happy programmers, ASP classic and MySQL (5.0) used to get along fine. ODBC (3.51) was their friend and data would flow from the heavens (read: database) without any issues.

Then, one day, a dark and mysterious event occurred. And now certain DataTypes within the MySQL Clan refuse to behave.

All of a sudden, TEXT stopped being available in the ASP object more than ONCE. Therefore any pre-test of *NOT NULL* became the end of the data in the object.

... Seriously. What the. You can see representations here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44831  and here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?132,220948,220948

**My question is:** Has anyone found out why this has started happening. I have *ZERO desire* to go back and edit 100's of sites to put the value into a var immediately after the recordset is filled.

Halp me superman!

We've tried upgrading to MySQL 5.6 and ODBC 5.1.sumthin & 5.2.5... but nothing helped. (We did decide that the ODBC version had no impact on the issue)

*Current production server remains at ODBC 3.51 + MySQL 5.0*
*Current test server comprises of ODBC 5.2.5 + MySQL 5.6*

**Edit:** Using ADODB Connection
ie:

```
dim oC, oRs
set oC = Server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")
oC.Open database

set oRs = oC.execute("SELECT 'garble garble garble garble' as `textthing`;")
if not oRs.eof then
    for x = 0 to 3
        response.write "Output: "
        response.write oRs("textthing") &"<br />"
    next
end if
oRs.close
set oRs = nothing
oC.close
set oC = nothing
```

This results in:
Output: garble garble garble garble
Output: 
Output: 
Output:

(I'd ask for some latitude here: the above text string -> remember it's coming out as a TEXT or MEDIUMTEXT for the sake of this exercise.)

**Edit 2:**
*(As noted in a comment below)*
The working solution we have is this:

1. Change things that really don't need to be ***TEXT to VARCHAR(BigEnough).
2. And edit the ASP for things that need to be ***TEXT to put the value
   straight into a variable.

This is far from being a great solution, however it does force you to consider your data more accurately - which can only be a good thing... right?

Comment: Are you using ADODB connection or recordset when retrieving data?

Comment: An ADODB.Connection. I'll amend the question

Comment: Ok, if you try to use a recordset instead? You only need to change three rows.
row 2: set oRs = Server.createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
row 3: not needed
row 5: oRs.open "SELECT `textthing` FROM tablename;",database

The rest stays the same...

Comment: Awww.. I was hoping that there might be another answer. There are over 1000 websites and many calls within each of those sites. To change everything would be a huge amount of work. :( I will give this a shot - but this isn't going to suit as a final solution.

Comment: Try looking for cursortype, cursorlocation and locktype on the recordset object (I think you should rework your code to explicitly create a recordset object instead of creating it with the connection object)

Comment: So, the working solution we have is this: 
Change things that really don't need to be ***TEXT to VARCHAR(BigEnough). And edit the ASP for things that need to be ***TEXT to put the value straight into a variable.

Comment: *(Also, I have a feeling that MaxiWheat is on to something there. If someone else comes across this issue.)*

Answer (score 0):

Mark, I'm taking a long shot here. For what I know of Classical ASP (which consists in years of swearing and loving), a NULL answer from the MySQL database results in... nothing, actually. Unless you define the recordset result as a string, it won't be comparable with a `""`. So, either you do this:

```
var recordsetVal = oRs("textthing")&""
```

... or you could simply do this:

```
if oRs("textthing")&"" <> "" then
```

Also, instead of `while ... wend`, use a `do while...loop` lace. It might work.
Again, this is a long shot. many factors could be involved in this question, but MySQL Driver and ODBC compatibility issue is only one of them and, fortunately, the least probable. Keep us posted.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric. In this case, there IS text in the response from the database (because it's a fictitious example). But the point is, it's there for access 1, but not anything further. :(   I have edited the question code to reflect this more obviously.

Comment: Hmmmm,... thats odd. I could have sworn it was a null-type string problem. 
Honestly, I'm lost here... I'll try to think a little further here.
Oh, BTW, you've sliced out the rs.MoveNext from the edited code. I know it was there before, but if someone else comes in and it is not there, they might think that that's where the problem at.

Comment: Yes, no movenext is intentional - since I am selecting 1 thing, and showing what happens with that. (I'll change it so it's a string and people will get the idea)